# ajax submit success, function not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I havent been using jQuery all that long, but I have this form, which is submitting data to my MVC controller without problems, the data is being saves, and my success function is being hit, becuase if I put an alert("thing") in there, it gets fired.  Also my ClearFields() function is getting fired.  However, my GetSamples(projId) function which using ajax, gets me a list of samples for projectId, isnt firing, but it does fire on pageload.

below is my code... if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great cause I can't see why its not working

```
 $(function () {

    var projectId = "@Model.Project.Id";

    GetSamples(projectId);

    $("#refreshButton").button().click(function () {
        GetSamples(projectId);
    });

    $("#saveSampleButton").button().click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PreRegistration/AddSample",
            type: "POST",
            data: { projectId: projectId,
                customerSampleId: $("#CustomerSampleId").val(),
                customerSampleId2: $("#CustomerSampleId2").val(),
                customerSampleId3: $("#CustomerSampleId3").val(),
                customerSampleId4: $("#CustomerSampleId4").val(),
                matrix: $("#Matrix").val(),
                product: $("#Product").val(),
                productGrade: $("#ProductGrade").val(),
                dueDate: $("#DueDate").val()
            },
            success: function (response, projectId, jqXHR) {
                alert("done");
                ClearFields();
                GetSamples(projectId);
            },
            error: function (xyz) {
                alert("Something went wrong : " + xyz.val());
            }               
        });

        return false;
    });



    $("#DueDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

    function ClearFields() {
        $("#CustomerSampleId").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId2").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId3").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId4").val("");
        $("#Matrix").val("");
        $("#Product").val("");
        $("#ProductGrade").val("");
        $("#DueDate").val("");
    }

    function GetSamples(pId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PreRegistration/GetSamples",
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: pId },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#ProjectSamples tbody").replaceWith(response)
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I have made a couple of changes to the code now, because I can see partly what was causing my problem, the GetSamples() function appears to be firing, but its not updating the table...

```
$(function () {

    var projectId = "@Model.Project.Id";

    GetSamples(projectId);

    $("#saveSampleButton").button().click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PreRegistration/AddSample",
            type: "POST",
            data: { projectId: projectId,
                customerSampleId: $("#CustomerSampleId").val(),
                customerSampleId2: $("#CustomerSampleId2").val(),
                customerSampleId3: $("#CustomerSampleId3").val(),
                customerSampleId4: $("#CustomerSampleId4").val(),
                matrix: $("#Matrix").val(),
                product: $("#Product").val(),
                productGrade: $("#ProductGrade").val(),
                dueDate: $("#DueDate").val()
            },
            success: function (projectId) {
                ClearFields();
                GetSamples(projectId);
            },
            error: function (xyz) {
                alert("Something went wrong : " + xyz.val());
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



    $("#DueDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

    function ClearFields() {
        $("#CustomerSampleId").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId2").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId3").val("");
        $("#CustomerSampleId4").val("");
        $("#Matrix").val("");
        $("#Product").val("");
        $("#ProductGrade").val("");
        $("#DueDate").val("");
    }

    function GetSamples(projectId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PreRegistration/GetSamples",
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: projectId },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#ProjectSamples tbody").replaceWith(response)
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Have debugged, and the projectId (1) is being passed into the function correctly.  In VS, on my controller action, the data is being fetched and passed back to the view... but the table is not being re-populated

Comment: as a side note.. is there anything out there that I can use to debug javascript?? It would be handy to know what is actually being passed into my GetSamples(xx) function, I have a sneaking suspision that the projectId isnt actually getting in there, except for on the page load... which would be why the function isnt working, but I have no way to debug it...

Comment: Can you put a break point in getSamples()  and in the begnning of the success function?  U getting any errors?

Comment: how do I put a breakpoint?? I dont know of anything to debug with.  Visual Studio doesnt debug javascript as far as I can tell??

Comment: open your page in chrome and follow the instructions in 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: alternatively can you alert projectID in the getSamples()? are u getting any script errors?

Comment: also you dont need to pass in projectId in the success function as it is already globally available

Comment: thank you Sajjan,  I have found the problem.  the success is returning response: 1 (which is actually projectId) and projectId: "success", so I have the params around the wrong way.

Comment: now that I know how to debug, it makes things a lot easier! :)

Comment: by the way you can also debug in IE in roughly the same way by hitting F12 to launch the debugger.. But I prefer Chrome as it shows the XHR request/responses too

Comment: yeah, but who would want to use IE?? lol

Comment: true dat my friend,true dat :)